# What is the difference between reactor.ipc.netty.tcp.TcpServer and reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer?

Tags: reactor-netty

I was trying to implement TCPServer using Reactive Netty.
I see two TcpServer class : reactor.ipc.netty.tcp.TcpServer and reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer

What is the difference between the two ?
I don't see reference to reactor.ipc.netty.tcp.TcpServer in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reactor.ipc.netty.tcp.TcpServer` is the API for creating TCP server provided in Reactor Netty versions <= 0.7.x
In versions >= 0.8.x there was a change in the API so that you have now `reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer`
Reactor Netty versions <= 0.7.x reached EOL so consider using versions >= 0.8.x